# Error with CakePHP 3.5 and Crud plugin (Uncaught Exception on CrudComponent.php)

Tags: php, cakephp, crud

I have a problem implementing the plugin [friendsofcake/crud](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/crud), version 5.4.1, on a clean install of [CakePHP 3.5](https://cakephp.org) with the Api, ApiPagination and ApiQueryLog listeners. I'm using PHP 7.0 on a Ubuntu.
I've followed the [instalation steps](http://crud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) from the docs and also [this tutorial](http://www.bravo-kernel.com/2015/04/how-to-build-a-cakephp-3-rest-api-in-minutes/), but i'm facing a strange issue.
Every request to the CRUD API crash and the stack trace points to line 540 on CrudComponent.
I've revised the plugin code and found where the exception is thrown and how to fix it, but I don't want to change the library's code. The exception is caused because when the Api listener is used the Crud.beforeRender event returns a Response object, if I comment out the "throw $Exception" line everything works as expected.

This is the library's code (Controller/Component/CrudComponent.php):

```
public function trigger($eventName, Subject $data = null)
{
    $eventName = $this->_config['eventPrefix'] . '.' . $eventName;

    $Subject = $data ?: $this->getSubject();
    $Subject->addEvent($eventName);

    if (!empty($this->_config['eventLogging'])) {
        $this->logEvent($eventName, $data);
    }

    $Event = new Event($eventName, $Subject);
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch($Event);

    if ($Event->result instanceof Response) {
        $Exception = new Exception();
        $Exception->response = $Event->result;
        throw $Exception;
    }

    return $Event;
}
```

If anyone have any idea of what is causing this strange behaviour, I'll appreciate any help.
PS: I'm sorry if I made any mistakes when writing, english isn't my mother tongue.
[Image capture of the stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKE7o.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Well to me it looks like one of your listeners is changing the `$event->result` to be a `Response` object.

Or one of the event listeners is retuning a response object which in turn changes `$event->response`.

Disable/remove all listeners and add them back one by one to see which is causing the issue.

The stack trace indicates a *crud.beforeRender* event being intercepted